# How to use regex to find functions call themself?

Tags: python, regex, shell, awk

I have a `code.py`:

```
def funA():
    print('A')
    funA()

def funB():
    print('B')

def funC():
    print('C')
    funB()
    funC()
```

I want to find all functions call themself:

```
funA
funC
```

How to write the `regex`?

**Constraint:**

- All function call is normal: `funname(arg1, arg2, ...)`
- No obfuscated ways(such as `lambda`,`exec`)
- No indirect recursion

Comment: Why would you write a regex instead of walking the AST?

Comment: It's going to be impossible to find all recursive functions with just a regex since Python's grammar is context-free.

Comment: Do you really still insist on using a regex for this? I think we made it quite clear that this is not possible.

Comment: Jobs like this are what parsers are *for*. And you already have a parser for Python built into Python, so you don't even have to write a parser yourself, just read some module docs on how to traverse the AST once you've got it. This is a task that is very hard (and provably can only be done approximately) with regexes, but is very easy with a parser. So use a parser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I do believe that it would be impossible for a regex to match the cases pointed out by wim where the self call is obfuscated. However, here is a regex that will do a semi decent job for straightforward self calls (in the form `funcname(...)`). This regex correctly matches all the test cases spelled out in the original question:

```py
reobj = re.compile(r"""
    # Match (unreliably) Python function with self reference.
    ^                        # Anchor to start of line.
    ([ \t]*)                 # $1: Indentation of DEF statement.
    def[ \t]+                # Function definition.
    ([^\s(]+)                # $2: Name of function to find.
    .*\r?\n                  # Remainder of function def line.
    (?:                      # Zero or more lines w/o funcname.
      (?:                    # Function block lines alternatives.
        \1[ \t]+             # Func block lines have extra indentation.
        (?:(?!\b\2\s*\().)*  # Optional non-funcname stuff on line
      | [ \t]*\#.*           # Allow comment lines to defy indent rules.
      )?                     # Allow blank lines in function block.
      \r?\n                  # End of line not containing funcname.
    )*                       # Zero or more lines w/o funcname
    \1[ \t]+                 # Now match the line having funcname.
    (?:(?!\b\2\s*\().)*      # Optional non-funcname stuff on line
    \b\2\s*\(                # Match the function self reference.
    """, re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
```

It matches starting with the function definition line and captures the whitespace indentation before the `'def'` in group `$1` and the function name in group `$2`. It then matches lines within the function block that do not contain the function name which each have more leading whitespace than the function definition. It skips over empty lines and lines containing only comments. It declares a match once it finds a line in the function block which has the function name followed by a left parentheses, indicating a call to itself. Otherwise, it declares a non-match then continues looking for the next possible match.

Note that this solution is unreliable and will result in false positives if the name of the function occurs inside a string or inside a comment following other code on a line. It also does not handle functions with multi-line raw strings. However, it will correctly catch quite a few!

Comment: This is like giving a guy a weed-whacker to trim his nostril hairs.

Comment: Not exactly. This answer simply answers the specific question that was asked, complete with a disclaimer on its (very real) limitations. For a one time search through a source file, this answer could certainly be useful. Just curious, would the ast module work any better at finding the special cases you cited? How difficult would that solution be? Why not post it? IMO the only 100% accurate solution would be to thoroughly profile/debug the application running all possible paths. But yes, this solution is definitely a weedwhacker! (which is what was asked for.)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard, because the function can call itself in obfuscated ways.  E.g., does this count?

```
def funA():
  print 'A'
  foo = funA
  foo()

funA()
```

What about this?

```
def funA():
  funB()

def funB():
  funA()

funA()
```

Or even this?

```
def funA():
  exec('Anuf'[::-1] + '()')

funA()
```

I don't think you can do it with a regex.

---

Even considering your new edits, it will still be very difficult if not impossible.  Consider this function for example.

```
def funA():
  if 1 + 1 == 2:
    return
  funA()
```

I suggest you follow the advice of Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams and look at [ast](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html).

Comment: Actually it's a fact that you _can't_ do it with a regular expression.

Comment: I suspected so too, but I don't like "proof by assertion"  :)

Comment: It's very easy to prove that Python is not a regular language.

Comment: "proof by intimidation" is not much better  :)

Comment: Every word in the non-regular language of well-formed parentheses is a valid Python program. Every word that is a combination of `(` and `)` but is not in this language is not a valid Python program. Therefore the subset of Python that only consists of parantheses is non-regular. Therefore Python is a non-regular language.

Comment: now you're talking!  but i don't think this helps the OP as much as a few simple examples, demonstrating some of the difficulties.

Comment: Of course not! But you didn't accept the two other forms of proving my point that I tried before ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you won't be able to do this with regex. You'll need to at least parse function definitions, keep some kind of state as to what function you are currently parsing, and search for the a call of the current function name within the scope of the current function.

Answer (score 0):

I'll describe the pattern that I think you want:  a line that starts with def, followed by whitespace, followed by a name (which you capture in parentheses), followed by a (possibly empty) set of lines that start with white space, followed by a line that starts with white space and contains your function name followed by an open paren (so that you capture an actual call, and not just a reference).

Comment: Not empty-  in Python you must use the `pass` statement instead of an empty body.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure `def funA(): funA()` is a valid Python function that calls itself. If it was followed immediately by another global scope statement, there would be no lines starting with whitespace following the `def`.  However Scott's description of a regex also wouldn't match this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

may be you could use gawk, below is my sample code, you may need to modify it:

```
#! /usr/bin/gawk -f
{
    currentLine = $0
    if (currentLine ~ /def/){
        inFunction = "true"
        nameIndex = index($2,"(")
        functionName = substr($2,1,nameIndex - 1)
        #print functionName
        next
    }
    if (inFunction == "true" && currentLine ~ functionName){
       inFunction = false 
       print "recursive function is: " functionName
    }
}
```

just run the program you will get what you want.